# Rspec: Test an exception which is not handled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

In my public method #recalculate, calling the private `method1`. This method throw exception 'StandardError'. I want to test this scenario, however getting an error.

**Note: I don't want to handle an exception.**

```
def recalculate
  method_1
end

private
def method_1
    ## do some calculation
    raise StandardError.new("Test")
end
```

Rspec Test case:

```
  it "Test" do
    expect { @product.recalculate.recalculate }.to raise_error(StandardError)
    @product.recalculate
  end

1) Product.Test 
  Failure/Error: @product.recalculate
   StandardError:
     Test
   (required)>'
```

Finished in 1.39 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, the second line `@product.recalculate` raises an actual exception hence the error. Assuming `recalculate` method is defined in `@product` object, this should be enough to test it.

```
it "Test" do
  expect { @product.recalculate }.to raise_error(StandardError)
end
```